# cudaBindTextureToArray and asynchronous operation

Tags: cuda

I'm doing asynchronous operations in CUDA. I have the following code:

```
    cudaBindTextureToArray( tex, ptr1, ... )   // bind texture to cuda array 1.

    Kernel1<<<,,,stream>>>                     // async. kernel1 that uses tex.

    cudaBindTextureToArray( tex, ptr2, ... )   // bind texture to cuda array 2.

    Kernel2<<<,,,stream>>>                     // async. kernel2 that uses tex.
```

I have to questions:

- Can I safely assume that Kernel1 is executed after the texture has been bound to cuda array 1?
- Can I safely assume that Kernel2 is executed after the texture has been bound to cuda array 2?

Comment: `cudaBindTextureToArray` is a synchronous call, so... yes, your assumption is correct.

Comment: Will this call then block all preceding requested tasks on the device (Like cudaDeviceSynchronize())? Or will it only wait untill cudaBindTextureToArray() has completed?

Comment: Luc, yes, I believe that if you want full asynchrony in the sequence, you need to use separate texture references to avoid the bind call.

If you can target SM 3.x or later, use texture objects.

Comment: I did a small experiment and apparently neither `cudaBindTextureToArray()` nor `cudaUnbindTextureToArray()` block the host. However, it seems that calls to these 2 functions, and asynchronous kernel launches execute sequentially on the GPU.